# Dictonary is stored wrongly in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to store data from my c# web API into my MongoDB database. The problem I am facing is one of my data is a dictionary. I do get the correctly serialised data in the c# when I debug, but when I store it into the MongoDB, it is stored as

```
"justice-supreme-court" : {
   "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
   "_v" : [{
             "_t" : "JObject",
             "_v" : [{
                        "_t" : "JProperty",
                        "_v" : [{
                                   "_t" : "JValue",
                                   "_v" : [ ]
                                }]
                     }]
           }]
          },
    "referendum-michigan-up" : "yes"
},
```

As suggestions from other posts I tried to change the Dictionary type to IDictionary, but with no help.

This is my object

```
public class EncyptBallotDbObject 
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Ballot")]
    public Ballot Ballot { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Votes { get; set; }

    //public Election? Election { get; set; }
    //public ElectionGuardConfig? ElectionGuardConfig { get; set; }
    //public ElectionMap? ElectionMap { get; set; }
    public string Tracker { get; set; }
    //public int? CurrentNumberOfBallots { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedBallotMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I add my value

```
 encyptballotDbObj.Ballot.Votes = request.Ballot.Votes;
 encyptballotDbObj.Votes = (Dictionary<string, object>)request.Ballot.Votes;
```

And this is how votes are declared

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Votes { get; set; }
```

The Json data I am trying to add is

```
"votes": {
    "justice-supreme-court" : [
        {
            "id": "laurel-clark"

        }
    ],
    "referendum-michigan-up" : "yes"
}
```

Comment: so it not string the correct value of json ? Can you show us the json data which you are inserting into databse? I dont know about mongodb, is it related to dataytype size?

Comment: your class structore shuld be this according to the json. 
`    public class JusticeSupremeCourt
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Votes
    {
        public IList<JusticeSupremeCourt> justice-supreme-court { get; set; }
        public string referendum-michigan-up { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public Votes votes { get; set; }
    }
`